IIS "501 Server cannot accept argument" on FTPS connection (Active mode)
I'm experiencing "501 Server cannot accept argument" on IIS FTPS server while trying to connect from client using active mode. The error exhibit on PORT command.
Here is the full log output of the client:
220 Microsoft FTP Service
AUTH TLS
234 AUTH command ok. Expecting TLS Negotiation.
USER ********
331 Password required
PASS ************
230 User logged in.
PBSZ 0
200 PBSZ command successful.
PROT P
200 PROT command successful.
FEAT
211-Extended features supported:
 LANG EN*
 UTF8
 AUTH TLS;TLS-C;SSL;TLS-P;
 PBSZ
 PROT C;P;
 CCC
 HOST
 SIZE
 MDTM
 REST STREAM
211 END
OPTS UTF8 ON
200 OPTS UTF8 command successful - UTF8 encoding now ON.
SYST
215 Windows_NT
CWD /
250 CWD command successful.
TYPE A
200 Type set to A.
PORT 192,168,1,100,236,141
501 Server cannot accept argument.
CWD /
250 CWD command successful.
TYPE A
200 Type set to A.
PORT 192,168,1,100,236,142
501 Server cannot accept argument.
CWD /
250 CWD command successful.
TYPE A
200 Type set to A.
PORT 192,168,1,100,236,143
501 Server cannot accept argument.
QUIT
221 Goodbye.

IIS is configured standard and active is enabled by default.
This configuration works with plain FTP.
Any help is appreciated.

What argument (e.g. port command) was sent? How is IIS configured? Is active mode disabled?

I added the requested informations. Thanks for your reply

Is this answer you ? https://serverfault.com/q/842192/256639

Long section of code should be formatted differently from the inline code syntax, if you read the Markdown syntax guide.

@yagmoth555 Not really. The proposed solution is misleading since PORT command should refer to ports and not IP addresses.

@Patrick_x11 I linked it as I seen in your port command the local IP (192.168.1.100), if the connection is made via another network/WAN that command will fail

@yagmoth555 My bad. The arguments of the PORT command are indeed the IP address along with port numbers. Not sure why the client is sending local IP address on active mode. Using Cyberduck on Win11. Thanks for your reply

@Patrick_x11 You can tell the ftp client to use the public ip usually, but it's a change to do manually each time, kinda why pasv mode is more used more to break that problem
